# WIF generating duplicate FedAuth cookies

Tags: wif, adfs

We have an web application in which we are using AD FS for authentication, everything is working fine till produciton. but recently we observer FedAuth and FedAuth1 cookies generated by WIF are getting duplciated. In fiddler trace i am able to see **FedAuth, FedAuth1, FedAuth and FedAuth1** with same values. This happening only in UAT and PROD environemnts and the lower environments have no issues like this. AD FS key configurations and code is same across all environments except environment specific attributes.  any help what went wrong ? we use loadbalancer in all environemnts and we dont use sticky sessions.

Comment: really identical, including validity, path etc?

Comment: yes... we enabled single server on farm and tried and there is no luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Resolved: We have health check monitor service running on UAT and PROD servers. Along with regular web application request, health check monitor is also sending some requests to check the health of the web application and it is generating another set of fed auth cookies. We stopped  health check monitor service and tested the app and then we no more observed duplicate cookies in fiddler.

Comment: It doesnt seem like good form to accept your answer and ask new question as part of the answer.  This should probably be in its own question, referencing the fist question/answer...

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you use different machine keys accross the machines ?  IMHO you need all servers  that are loadbalanced to have the same machine key and to configure them to use [machinekeysessionsecuritytokenhandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.services.tokens.machinekeysessionsecuritytokenhandler(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: i have double checked this machine key is not auto generated and used the samae key across farm servers

Comment: Another (tiny) possibility is that you have more than one app configured on the same address.  Maybe you want to change the name of the default cookie to make sure about this.  It's just a wild guess I admit.  You can change it in the <cookieHandler name="OtherName"> configuration element.

Comment: on same VIP ADFS registration mutliple apps are running, i have stopped all apps except one and tried.. no luck... same setup is working properly in other lower environments